# Is there any reference for Gazebo exit code list?

Tags: ros2, gazebo-11

Im using Gazebo classic for a while now. Errors such as:

> [gzserver-1]: process has died [pid 2622, exit code *<*number*>*...]

Are a really common thing and I wondered if there is any reference for the complete exit code list somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that there is a documented list of Gazebo exit codes and some of the could come from calls to third party libraries. Most useful measures to help to known whats happening:

- Run `gazebo --verbose` to obtain a detailed log of what's going on.
- Check `~/.gazebo/` directory to review the logs, specially the `ogre.log`.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Well, a "No" answer is still an answer. Thanks :)